# Book on problems about Riemann integral that are solved by another integrals

Tags: reference-request

Some time ago I found a book (don't remember if it was about integration or real analysis in general) that stated three concrete problems that Riemann integral has (about convergence, primitives, etc.) before introducing other types of integrals that solve that problems.
I cannot remember any more detail of the book apart from the fact that it introduces exactly three problems the Riemann integral has at the end of some chapter.

The exposition of this problems and the examples to illustrate them were really good, so I was hoping if someone would know which book is it, altough my description is so vague.

Thanks in advance for any reply.